# Filter records from one file based on a values present in another file using Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have an Input csv file [Input feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt8Xa.jpg)

```
PK,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5    
A,1,2,3,4,5
B,1,A,B,C,D
C,1,2,3,4
D,2,1,2,3
E,5,1,1,1
F,8,1,1,1
```

There is an output error csv file which is generated from this input file which has the Primary Key

[Error File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg3ug.jpg)

```
    Pk,Error_Reason   
    D,Failure
    E, Failure
    F, Failure
```

I want to extract all the records from the input file and save it into a new file for which there is a Primary key entry in Error file.

Basically my new file should look like this:

[New Input feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOqix.jpg)

```
PK,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5    
D,2,1,2,3
E,5,1,1,1
F,8,1,1,1
```

I am a beginner in Unix and I have tried Awk command.

The Approach I have tried is, get all the primary key values into a file.

akw -F"," '{print $2}' error.csv >> error_pk.csv

Now I need to filter out the records from the input.csv for all the primary key values present in error.pk

Comment: Post same sample data in text; images aren't usable for testing.

Comment: Hi James, I have added some reference test data.

Comment: I don’t suppose you could use Python?

Comment: `join` ? `Pk` differs from `PK`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk. As there is leading space in the error file, it needs to be trimmend off first, I'm using `sub` for that. Then, since the titles of the first column are not identical, (PK vs Pk) that needs to be handled separately with `FNR==1`:

```
$ awk -F, '                      # set separator
NR==FNR {                        # process the first file
    sub(/^ */,"")                # trim leading space
    a[$1]                        # hash the first column
    next  
}
FNR==1 || ($1 in a)' error input # output tthe header record and if match hashed
```

Output:

```
PK,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5    
D,2,1,2,3
E,5,1,1,1
F,8,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`.

First remove everything afte the comma from second file
Join on the first field from both files

```
cat <<EOF >file1
PK,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5    
A,1,2,3,4,5
B,1,A,B,C,D
C,1,2,3,4
D,2,1,2,3
E,5,1,1,1
F,8,1,1,1
EOF

cat <<EOF >file2
PK,Error_Reason   
D,Failure
E,Failure
F,Failure
EOF

join -t, -11 -21 <(sort -k1 file1) <(cut -d, -f1 file2 | sort -k1)
```

If you need the file to be sorted according to `file1`, you can number the lines in first file, join the files, re-sort using the line numbers and then remove the numbers from the output:

```
join -t, -12 -21 <(nl -w1 -s, file1 | sort -t, -k2) <(cut -d, -f1 file2 | sort -k1) |
sort -t, -k2 | cut -d, -f1,3-
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -f` with a file with search items. Cut off at the `,`.

```
grep -Ef <(sed -r 's/([^,]*).*/^\1,/' file2) file1
```

When you want a header in the output,